# Extra Argument Call In Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to convert my Swift 3.2 code in Swift 4.2.  I have a class as below

```
class Bindable<T>{
    typealias Listener = ((T) -> Void)
    var listener: Listener?

    var value: T {
        didSet {
            listener?(value)
        }
    }

    init(_ v: T) {
        self.value = v
    }

    func bind(_ listener: Listener?) {
        self.listener = listener
    }

    func bindAndFire(_ listener: Listener?) {
        self.listener = listener
        listener?(value)
    }

}
```

In Swift 3.2, If I write below

```
public var otpField = Bindable("")
public var validationErrorText = Bindable(false, "")
public var otp_Status = Bindable(false, "")
public var bindableLoadingObjectOtp = Bindable(false, "")
```

It's working fine but when I tried to convert in 4.2 I got error '*Extra argument in call*' (See below image)

[image]

Please let me know what am I doing wrong while converting in Swift 4.2

Comment: I doubt that the code works in Swift 3 

Comment: @vadian :) but its working.

Comment: makes no sense, you can't pass two arguments creating an instance from a class with only one variable in the init signature! you probably missing something.

Comment: I can confirm that this code has compiled in Swift 3 and raise compilation error in Swift 4 ;)

Comment: Just delete the ***extra argument***, the empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3, the two arguments get implicitly converted to a single tuple argument so `Bindable(false, "")` creates an object of type `Bindable<(Bool, String)>`.

Swift 4.2 apparently doesn't do this implicit tuple conversion so you would need to do `Bindable((false, ""))` to get the same behavior.

Comment: Somewhere along the line they removed a lot of the implicit tuple handling in favor of clearer explicit handling.  This is one of the effects of that change.

Answer (score 0):

The initializer of your `Bindable<T>` class takes a single parameter, whereas you are calling it with multiple parameters for your `validationErrorText`, `otp_Status` and `bindableLoadingObjectOtp` variables.

Comment: yes,, but same code is working fine in Swift 3.2, I am facing error i n Swift 4.2

Answer (score 0):

You are passing two arguments into `Bindable` while `Bindable` only have one initializer,

You can add Another initializer

```
class Bindable<T>{
    typealias Listener = ((T) -> Void)
    var listener: Listener?

    var value: T {
        didSet {
            listener?(value)
        }
    }
    init (_ v:T){
        self.value = v
    }
    init(_ something: Bool,_ v: T) {
        self.value = v
    }

    func bind(_ listener: Listener?) {
        self.listener = listener
    }

    func bindAndFire(_ listener: Listener?) {
        self.listener = listener
        listener?(value)
}
}
```

Like this and Use the `Bool` arguments you are sending.

Comment: The question is "why this code is correct for Swift 3 and incorrect in Swift 4?"